# First call to toggleFullScreen: doesn't work (it used to!)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a document based application based on the Xcode template. It’s not using Core Data.

My application is very simple:

- Document window has Primary Window set for Full Screen collection behaviour in Interface Builder
- Toggle Fullscreen menu item works as expected, as does the window control.

In code, I am calling toggleFullScreen: using the following:

```
NSWindow * window = [NSApp mainWindow];
[window toggleFullScreen:self];
```

Once before a timer fires, and once after time period has finished to revert to non-full sceen mode.

Recently, it has simply stopped working - the first call has no effect whatsoever. I've set a breakpoint just before the first call and it just executes with no effect.

I’ve even set up a NSWindowDelegate class for testing, which responds to windowDidEnterFullScreen: and windowDidExitFullScreen: when user toggles full sreen manually using the menu item, or by using the standard window control.

The function windowDidFailToEnterFullScreen: in the delgate never gets called after the first toggle fails.

The second call (which uses **exact same code**) works - it takes the window into fullscreen (not out of fullscreen, as it is supposed to, due to first call not working).

Any ideas?

The frustrating thing is, this used to work! I have an older version of the application which does the same thing, using the same code, and it works fine. This killed my theory that it had something to do with upgrading to El Capitan.

So what could have happened? I cannot for the life of me work this out. Have I accidentally changed something in interface builder? Maybe my Project/Compiler settings?

Any help much appreciated!

Regards,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally cracked this after much hair-tearing.

The problem was the first call to toggleFullScreen: was called inside a block being used as the handler for an NSAlert.

For some reason, it now requires the NSAlert window to be closed manually before the toggle works.

Here is my solution:

```
- (IBAction) areYouSure:(NSButton *) sender {

    NSWindow *window = [NSApp mainWindow];


    // Ask the user if they are sure

    NSAlert * alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];

    // .. set up NSAlert ..

    [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:window completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {
        if (returnCode == NSAlertSecondButtonReturn)
        {        
            [[alert window] close]; // This line solved the problem!

            [window toggleFullScreen:self]; // Without above line, this does nothing.
        }
    }]; // end block
}
```

As I mentioned in my original post, this *used* to work before I updated to El Capitan, *without* the use of the [[alert window] close] call.

So, something must have changed, although I cannot find any documentation explaining the above behaviour.

My older version of the app was displaying the alert on a different window, and the call the toggleFullScreen was called on another window.

I'm guessing that the problem has something to do with the fact that the toggleFullScreen is called in a completion handler, and also that the call is on the same window that the NSAlert is attached to.

The NSAlert now has to be closed manually before the toggleFullScreen works.

Hope this will help someone out in the future!

Does anyone have any more info on this behaviour, and what might have changed in El Capitan to cause this?

Regards,

John

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning the project? Also clean the project build folder. Press cmd+shift+K, and then cmd+shift+opt+K in Xcode. Then re-build the project.

Comment: Many thanks for this. I just tried both, and problem is still there.

Comment: Although you have fixed the problem (well done!), there is still no need for an alert window. Maybe someone else will now how to fix this!

Comment: Not sure what you mean - due to the way my app is designed, I need the user to confirm yes or no before going full screen. Isn't this the standard way of using NSAlert?

Comment: Yes, but you still shouldn't have to ask for confirmation from the user before you app enters full screen. You should be able to enter full screen without the use of an NSAlert.

Comment: Actually, this is desired behaviour for my app when a user clicks a button. It's not a "typical" app. I realise it's not standard behaviour. Thanks!